# Use DOM IntelliSense instead of Node in VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have my DOM scripts under the `/src/public/js` directory and VS Code is giving me IntelliSense like if it was Node.js, it doesn't recognize that they are meant to run in the browser.

For example, it can auto-import modules (and it shouldn't), while it doesn't have any idea what "document" is.

How can I specify in Visual Studio Code that a given JavaScript file is a script for the browser and not for Node.js, so that I can have proper IntelliSense?

Comment: you can add `// @ts-ignore` lines to suppress certain errors, I have a VSC extension that has a WebView with javascript injected and I don't have an error on the `document` variable. The tooltip even tells me that it is of type `Document`